# can i compile .cpp file in to a dll file where the cpp file itself calls the functions from another dll file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017

So getting in to detail of my question :
I have cpp file which calls  functions from a dll file which is written in c.
Here is just an example code

**first.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"
#include <windows.h> 

typedef double(*MYFUN1)(double);
int main1(int k )
{
    MYFUN1  pfun1;
    HMODULE hMod;
    hMod = LoadLibrary(L"MyMathDll.dll");
    pfun1 = (MYFUN1)GetProcAddress(hMod, "PowerOf3"); 
    int ii, max = 20;

    for (ii = 0; ii < max; ii++)
    {
      printf("%le", pfun1(10));
    }
    return ii;
}
```

**header.h**

```
#pragma once
int main1(int k);
```

My MyMathDll.dll is formed by following two files:
**MyMathDll.c**

```
#include "MyMathDll.h"
 double PowerOf3(double UserNumber)
{
    return UserNumber * UserNumber * UserNumber;
}
```

**MyMathDll.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if defined (WIN32)
#if defined(FUNCTIONS_STATIC)
#define FUNCTIONS_API
#else
#if defined(FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS)
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif
#else
#define FUNCTIONS_API
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef MYMATHDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYMATHDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYMATHDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>

MYMATHDLL_API double PowerOf3(double UserNumber);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now I am compiling first.cpp to a dll file, so it's basically i am trying make a dll file which already calls the functions from another c dll file.

I built the project a dll file is generated. Now I am making new project with application type .exe and trying load the dll file which is generated from first.cpp 
example code of the second cpp which calls the functions from first.cpp

**second.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 
typedef int (*MYFUN4)(int );
void main()
{
    int  k = 10;
    MYFUN4  pfun4;
    HMODULE hMod2;
    hMod2 = LoadLibrary(L"first.dll");
    pfun4 = (MYFUN4)GetProcAddress(hMod2, "main1");


    printf("%d", pfun4(k));
    getchar();
}
```

when i try to run this application, I get a pop window with following message:

Exception triggered at 0x00000000 in ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when running at position 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may still run safely.

Comment: first.dll could be loaded, but `main1` was not defined in extern "C" block to avoid name mangling and was not exported by `__declspec(dllexport) ` as it was with `PowerOf3` function.

Comment: @rafix07 thank you it worked.

Comment: You gotta check for errors on both LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.